# How To Get A Distinct Count Using a Nested Case Query?

Tags: sql, count, distinct, case

I have an issue somewhat like:

[MySQL: Sum values in subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515193/mysql-sum-values-in-subqueries)

where I have a large where section that does some filtering and then want to do filtering in the select section when I'm doing different categories.

My situation is different in that I need to use a count distinct using case and not a sum: You have multiple orders and want to count the number of orders for a particular product (in addition to returning a bunch of other aggregates based on other conditions). However, due to technological issues, sometimes the order system will create two nearly identical rows that have the same ProductID and same OrderID (other columns will be slightly different such as time of order). However, you only want to count the number of *distinct* orders (eg only +1 for each unique OrderID) for a particular product. However for some other aggregates you need to use the duplicate entry, so you have to use a case subquery for count in the select section.

I created a query that *almost* works for this [sample database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left):

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductID)
, COUNT(CASE WHEN ProductID = 51 THEN DISTINCT OrderDetailID END) 
FROM OrderDetails
```

However it complains about a syntax error. As soon as I remove 'DISTINCT' it works fine, but this causes duplicates to be counted (which while they don't exist in the sample database, exist in mine) which is why I need 'DISTINCT' to work

Comment: Solving the underlying technical problem would probably be a better solution.

Comment: I agree, it's just this hypothetical description best matched the sample database coulmn names. I don't have the actual technical issue with what I'm doing, I just have a situation where a distinct count of something is needed amongst the returns of other complex aggregates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is quite close.  You just need to move the `distinct` before the `case`:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductID), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductID = 51 THEN OrderDetailID END) 
FROM OrderDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
select count(productid)
, case when productid = 51 then count(distinct orderdetailid)
else some other number end
from orderdetails
```

Comment: You can't use `productid` outside of an aggregate function that unless you `GROUP BY productid`