# Mysql subquery sum of votes

Tags: mysql

I've got a table of votes, alongside a table of 'ideas' (entries)

Basically, I want to retrieve an object that can be read as:

```
id,
name,
title,
votes : {
  up : x,
  down : y
}
```

So it's simple enough until I get to the subquery and need to do two sets of SUMs on the positive and negative values of votes.

```
SELECT id,name,title FROM ideas
LEFT JOIN votes ON ideas.id = votes.idea_id
```

My (simplified) votes table looks something like:

```
id
idea_id
value
```

Where `value` can be either a positive or negative `int`.

How would I go about getting the above object in a single query?

**Bonus point:** How would I also get an `aggregate` field, where positive and negative votes are added together?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515193/mysql-sum-values-in-subqueries?rq=1

`SUM(CASE WHEN ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. not tested.

```
SELECT 
id,
name,
title, 
SUM(case when value > 0 then value end) up,
SUM(case when value < 0 then value end) down
 FROM ideas
LEFT JOIN votes ON ideas.id = votes.idea_id
GROUP By id;
```

Comment: which `id` would it be grouped by? `ideas.id` ?

Comment: Also, this wouldn't make it a node of a `votes` child - any way of achieving that or would it be easier to just refactor my frontend? And does it return 0 if there's no SUM?

Comment: wait for the SQL experts to wake up, im sure this is solvable. (my other guess would be with subqueries, but that may be slow..)

Comment: ahk, yeah cool `=)` - I just tried and it returns `NULL` if there are no votes

Comment: btw.. your "bonus point" should be a third sum() without the value restriction. :D

Comment: Yeah I got that - it was a pretty simple bonus point, ha. I don't think it's possible to get it all inside a `vote` node because it'd end up being a multi-dimensional array...

Comment: I've figured out the `NULL` -> `0` thing with a mysql function called `COALESCE()`, which returns the first non-null value. Thanks for your help, I was able to build on your answer!